# Java Netty TCP message truncated at 1420 bytes intermittently upon channelread

Tags: java, tcp, netty, tcpserver, reactor-netty

Does anybody know how to fix this issue on truncated message when received by netty server? I tried to use native netty and reactor netty but Im still encountering the same issue. I tried to use different decoders/encoders as well but nothing solve my problem. I've tried to change frame length configurations as well. This happens once every 500-1000 requests. This doesn't happen if server and client resides in the same machine. I was expecting 1494 bytes but sometimes I only received 1420 bytes

```
public final class Server {
    public  static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {

            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup,workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ServerInitializer());
            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(8888);
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}


@Sharable
public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<byte[]> {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] request) throws Exception {
        ChannelFuture future = ctx.write(request);
        future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}

public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {
    private static final ServerHandler SERVER_HANDLER = new ServerHandler();

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast(SERVER_HANDLER);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a `Logginghandler` on the child channel and see if the bytes were read but not received by your handler or they were not even read by netty

Comment: I already did that but I found nothing helpful. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: 1420 bytes payload seems suspiciously close to a full frame ethernet+IP+TCP traffic: 1512 - (14+20+20+..) (headers being different sizes based on optional components - and the overall max frame size being quite different based on the underlying interface: VPN, loopback, etc). So I'd focus on the frame decoder. You've chosen a delimiter based one, so I'm guessing each line its arriving to your handler's read event separately, right? And since you're complaining there are truncated cases, there are lines > 1420 bytes? In any case, Wireshark is your friend in understanding frame boundaries!